# bot with selenium and i can't figure out this error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, bots

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



class Twitter:
    def __init__(self,mail):
        self.mail = mail
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(10)
```

error :  driver: WebDriver
No value for argument 'url' in unbound method call

tried to chage "" -> '' it didn't worked..

Comment: You forgot to call the constructor, it is `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`... By not constructing an instance, you call it as a function, and it is missing the `self` (well it sees `"https://..."` as `self`, but it is thus missing an `url`).

Comment: Thank you!! :) and for editing (new around here) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.driver = webdriver.Firefox`

should be:

`self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()`